# How to enable the number pad keys to display number in a label in VB

Tags: visual-studio-2010, key, numpad

I am very new to VB and to gain more experience I'm trying to build a calculator. I have it in a working form but would like to enable the number pad keys to input the number to a label. I've tried searching but no luck. All the info I've seen is old which may be why its not working. If you can help that would be great! Thanks!

Ok, I have found and modified this code and it got me a step further by printing the number to the label but now I cannot figure out how enter a row of numbers. After each keydown it removes the previous keyed number to replace with the new number. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
Sub Calculator_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar >= ChrW(48) And e.KeyChar <= ChrW(57) Then
        Label1.Text = e.KeyChar.ToString()

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surly need some sleep I should have known this.. Since there is many people out there looking for this answer I'm just going to leave it up.

CORRECT CODE:

```
Sub Calculator_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar >= ChrW(48) And e.KeyChar <= ChrW(57) Then
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + e.KeyChar.ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```